# Error in Junit testcases for a contoller file

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to spring boot and Junit. I am writing a small Junit testcase for my controller.
My controller file looks like below:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/project-files")
    public class MyController {

        private RequestModel setRequestModel(String params) {
        RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel();
        requestModel.setRequestData(params);
        return requestModel;
        }

        @PostMapping("/deleteUploadedFile")
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> deleteUploadedFile(@RequestParam(value = "requestData", required = false)    String params) {
        RequestModel requestModel = setRequestModel(params);
        return service.deleteUploadedFile(requestModel);
        }
    }
```

Based on the reference from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_rest_controller_unit_test.htm) I tried to write a junit tescases for my controller.

My Junit Testcases looks like below:

```
    package com.test.project.web;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
    import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyMap;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

    import com.test.project.beans.RequestModel;
    import com.test.project.service.serviceImpl;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
    public class MyControllerTest<mapFromJson> {

    @InjectMocks
    private serviceImpl serviceImpl;

    @InjectMocks
    dataRepoImpl repoImpl;

    @InjectMocks
    MyController myController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController()).build();
    }

     protected <T> T mapFromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws
     JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
     
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); return
     objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz); 
     }
    

    @Test
    public void deletefile() throws Exception {
        String uri = "/deleteUploadedFile";
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andReturn();
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(200, status);
        String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        MyController[] productlist = super.mapFromJson(content, MyController[].class);
        assertTrue(productlist.length > 0);
        }
    }
```

I am getting errors

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Is there any other better way to write the Junit testcases for controller?

```
 @Test public void deletefile() throws Exception { 
      MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/project-files/deleteUploadedFile") //Getting error in post.
                .param("params", "some_value_here"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()); //Getting error in status
      String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(); 
      productlist = super.mapFromJson(content, MrmController[].class); //Getting error in productlist & mapFromJson
      assertTrue(productlist.length > 0);
  }
```

Comment: Please post entire stacktrace, not just one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .andExpect() method to validate the status of the request instead of using assertEquals()

You can use something in the lines of this to test your endpoint call:

```
 mockMvc.perform(post("/project-files/deleteUploadedFile")
                .param("params", "some_value_here"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Some strange things I find inside of your controller is that you use @PostMapping for deleting you can use @DeleteMapping instead [see spring docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/DeleteMapping.html)

Also, you should use more descriptive names for parameter names (and in general)

> String params

don't really ring a bell as to what this variable is representing.

If the issue persists make sure to post the entire stacktrace as suggested.

*Keep in mind when you're writing tests in general you are mimicking the behaviour of the real call, so don't add useless checks or mocks

```
@InjectMocks
    private serviceImpl serviceImpl;

    @InjectMocks
    dataRepoImpl repoImpl;
```

I don't see the above in your controller so I am not sure why are they part of the test.

Comment: Getting errors in the code. In the post, status, productlist & mapFromJson. Posted the code in the above question

Comment: in "some_value_here" you should put an actual value, I put that String there so you could replace it, and what is the error you're getting, please be more descriptive

Comment: I have added value for "some_value_here". Error - The method post(String) is undefined for the type MyControllerTest;           The method status() is undefined for the type MyControllerTest;      The method mapFromJson(String, Class<MyController[]>) is undefined for the type Object